# Should a levelling Prot Paladin use a 2her or sword/shield?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am levelling a Prot Paladin and am wondering if I would kill mobs faster with a two-hander or sword and shield?  The former gives me bigger numbers but the latter gives me Avengers Shield and Shield of the Righteous to rotate in.

This is all assuming the weapons are of comparable item levels.

Comment: I'm spending most of my time leveling in dungeons, which is why I'm dual-specced Prot/Holy (no Ret).  However when I just feel like doing some quests in the outside world, I want to which is generally better.

Comment: Pretty much the way to go while leveling(at least since mists released) is tank if you can, dps if you can't, and don't play heals unless you are in a group. Classes with tank specs tend to level the fastest and have insanely high survivability against large groups(i mean large groups, 10+) while traveling around Azeroth. If you are geared well enough while leveling, you can do most group quests by yourself as well, with little to relatively no trouble(even at or below what would have been recommended level).

Answer (score 2):

Have in mind that, you can also level in dungeons, where you will most likely need a shield. And, since you are tank specc'd, the queue will be almost instant for you, depending on the server.

About general leveling, i'm not sure, i would consider measuring the time you will take to kill each mob, and calculate the average time after killing like 20 mobs.

After that, do the same with the shield (After you get the Avenger's Shield and Shield of the Righteous ofc) and compare the times.

Simple as A B C.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are staying as a Prot Paladin then Sword and Shield, into the late 30's you will start doing max DPS in dungeons. Only go 2h if you are going to play Ret, as a Prot just stay sword and shield :)

Answer (score 1):

As a *Prot pally*, use a **shield/1H**, and **abuse** the fact that you practically get **insta-queues** as a tank for **dungeons** *(at least, I did on a lower population server)*. Questing is a good thing to do if you are *waiting for **queue***/tired of dungeons.

If you are farming quests, although a **2H** would *kill* the mobs **faster** *(even though you're not ret)*, the advantage of a prot pally is that you can round up 5-7 mobs, (depending on your lvl and theirs) and be able to **farm drops and amounts of kills needed** to complete the quest ***way faster***.

Answer (score 0):

Sword and shield. You're protection spec, abilities take advantage of your shield, so no point using a 2 hander.

Also, you're going to start being able to take down groups for which a shield will be a must if you don't want to get "pwned". ;)

The added benefit is you can LFG at will, and chain dungeons along the way. Not much wait time as a tank. A prot pally with a 2hander tanking = fail.